# Sequence that sum up to A343685

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, recurrences

- Let $a(n)$ be [A343685](https://oeis.org/A343685) i.e.
  $$
  a(n)=2na(n-1)+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{j}(n-j-1)!a(j), \\
  a(0)=1
  $$
  Here the exponential generating function $A(x)$ satisfy
  $$
  A(x)=\frac{1}{1-2x+\log(1-x)}
  $$
- Let $\operatorname{wt}(n)$ be [A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120) i.e. number of $1$'s in binary expansion of $n$ (or the binary weight of $n$). Here
  $$
  \operatorname{wt}(2n+1)=\operatorname{wt}(n)+1, \\
  \operatorname{wt}(2n)=\operatorname{wt}(n), \\
  \operatorname{wt}(0)=0
  $$
- Let $f(n)$ be [A025480](https://oeis.org/A025480) i.e.
  $$
  f(2n+1)=f(n), \\
  f(2n)=n
  $$
- Let
  $$
  g(n,m)=f(g(n,m-1)-1), \\
  g(n,0)=n
  $$
- Let
  $$
  b(n)=b\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\operatorname{wt}(n)}\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j}b(g(n,j)), \\
  b(0)=1
  $$
- Finally, let
  $$
  s(n)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2^n-1}b(j)
  $$

I conjecture that $$n!s(n)=a(n).$$

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
a_upto(n)=my(v1); v1=vector(n+1, i, 0); v1[1]=1; for(i=1, n, v1[i+1]=2*i*v1[i] + sum(j=0, i-1, binomial(i, j)*(i-j-1)!*v1[j+1])); v1
s_upto(n)=my(v1, v2); v1=vector(2^n, i, 0); v1[1]=1; v2=vector(n+1, i, 0); v2[1]=1; for(i=1, 2^n-1, my(A=0, B=i); for(j=1, hammingweight(i), B\=2^(valuation(B,2)+1); A+=(-1)^(j-1)/j*v1[B+1]); v1[i+1]=v1[i\2+1] + A); for(i=1, n, v2[i+1]=v2[i] + sum(j=2^(i-1)+1, 2^i, v1[j])); for(i=1, n, v2[i+1]*=i!); v2
test(n)=a_upto(n)==s_upto(n)
```

**Motivation**: random generalization of the conjectured recurrence for [A071585](https://oeis.org/A071585) (OEIS page already contain my conjecture).

Is there a way to prove it?